# I'm trying to create a pop-up window that occurs when you mouseover a clickable link. The code works, but I'm getting 26 errors on validator

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new at coding.  I need to create a hyperlink with an alert message that appears when the cursor moves over the hyperlink.  The code I have seems to work, but I'm getting 26 errors on the validator.  16 of the errors are on this line.  If someone can point me in the right direction here that would be great.

```
<a href="http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/" onmouseover="alert('Welcome to visit this hyperlink!');"http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/"><em>Frontline</em></a>
```

Comment: Please add errors to the question.

Comment: Please add the errors so that we can assist you.

Comment: Line 23, Column 108: No space between attributes.                                Line 23, Column 114: A slash was not immediately followed by >.     - This error shows up several times                                                      Line 23, Column 148: Saw " when expecting an attribute name. Probable cause: = missing immediately before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a random URL part way through your markup:

```
<a href="..." onmouseover="..." http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/">
```

This is causing all sorts of validation errors. Simply remove it (along with the trailing `"`):

```
<a href="..." onmouseover="...">
```

Comment: I tried taking that out just now, and the link disappears from the webpage completely.  I'm sorry, but I'm still confused.

Comment: @GretchenPapeCrigler there's no reason it should disappear. Have you kept the `href` and `onmouseover` attributes the same? Have you accidentally removed the `>` from the end of your tag?

Comment: yes.  Here is what I tried: <a href="http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/" onmouseover="alert('Welcome to visit this hyperlink!');><em>Frontline</em></a>        The link disappears completely

Comment: @GretchenPapeCrigler Well of course. You've randomly removed `"` characters and added a `;` character after your first URL. Why? It should look something like this: `<a href=".../frontline/" onmouseover="alert('...')">...</a>`

Comment: Yes - I understand now.  Thank you sooo much.  How do I give you credit for helping me?

Comment: @GretchenPapeCrigler Happy to help! You can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking on the green tick which appears below the score count found on the left of my answer.